# How to prevent creation of empty objects

Tags: mapstruct

I'm trying to map a model of a webservice where every List is inside nested object to something more simple.

1. Model 1

> ```
> public class Parent {
>    private Children children;
> }
>
> public class Children {
>    private List<Child> children;
> }
>
> public class Child {
> }
> ```

2. Model 2(simplified)

> ```
> public class Parent2 {
>    private List<Child2> children;
> }
>
> public class Child {
> }
> ```

The mapping is pretty straightforward:

> ```
> @Mappings({@Mapping(source = "entity.children.children", target = "children")})
> Parent2 parentToParent2(Parent entity);
> @InheritInverseConfiguration
> Parent parent2ToParent(Parent2 entity);
> ```

Mapping works fine except for one problem. When I map Parent with null children to Parent2 and back to Parent, the Children object is created with empty list. Is there some way to prevent that?

Comment: Just tested with 1.2.0.Final and I get `Parent` having non null `Children` object with a null `children` field (`Parent.children` is non-null, `Parent.children.children` is null). What would you expect? `Parent.children` to be null?

Comment: Yes, I'd like exactly that. Because as of now when I map Parent to Parent2 and back, I get different object than what I've started with.

Comment: hi.. Checkout https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1166. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. It looks like it won't be supported in the near future :(

Comment: It's on my to-do list. But it's a tricky one. I like to have it myself as well. Just need to find time to figure out a decent solution

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with both a [mapper decorator](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators) or an [AfterMapping hook](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after).

## Decorator

Decorator:

```
public abstract class MapperDecorator implements Mapper {

    private final Mapper delegate;

    public MapperDecorator(Mapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Parent parent2ToParent(Parent2 entity) {
        Parent parent = delegate.parent2ToParent(entity);

        if (entity.getChildren() == null) {
            parent.setChildren(null);
        }

        return parent;
    }
}
```

Mapper:

```
@org.mapstruct.Mapper
@DecoratedWith(MapperDecorator.class)
public interface Mapper {
    @Mapping(source = "entity.children.children", target = "children")
    Parent2 parentToParent2(Parent entity);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    Parent parent2ToParent(Parent2 entity);

    Child2 childToChild2(Child entity);

    Child child2ToChild(Child2 entity);
}
```

## AfterMapping

Mapper:

```
@org.mapstruct.Mapper
public abstract class Mapper {
    @Mapping(source = "entity.children.children", target = "children")
    public abstract Parent2 parentToParent2(Parent entity);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    public abstract Parent parent2ToParent(Parent2 entity);

    public abstract Child2 childToChild2(Child entity);

    public abstract Child child2ToChild(Child2 entity);

    @AfterMapping
    public void afterParent2ToParent(Parent2 source,
                                     @MappingTarget Parent target) {
        if (source.getChildren() == null) {
            target.setChildren(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of these possibilities and I ended up doing @AfterMapping, but I was interested in some automated way of doing that because I have many of these and forgetting something may be fatal. Apparently MapStruct doesn't support this so far.