# How to have MapStruct not generate wrapper object if property is null?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have some code that uses MapStruct to map a `from.id` to a `to.ref.id` structure. When `from.id` is null, MapStruct will create a new `Reference` instance and set its `id` to `null`. How do I instead make it not generate the wrapper class, and set `to.ref` to null?

I've tried different values for the mapping's `nullValueCheckStrategy` and `nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy`, but those don't seem to make any difference for this case.

This is my code, getters and setters omitted for brevity.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class).get(new From()));
    }
}

@Mapper
interface MyMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "ref.id")
    To get(From from);
}

class From {
    private String id;
}

class To {
    private Reference ref;
}

class Reference {
    private String id;
}
```

Comment: That's currently not possible. You have to use @AfterMapping method or a Decorator. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628177/how-to-prevent-creation-of-empty-objects

Comment: What if you don't directly map your from.id to to.ref.id? But instead map the from.id to a Reference class instance. You can create a mapper to map From to Reference  class instances and use that mapper to map your From and To class instances.

Comment: @greenPadawan that actually seems to work! Would you like to add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: should probably marked as duplicate then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this

Create a new mapper as follows.

```
@Mapper
public interface Mapper1 {
    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id")
    Reference get(String id);
}
```

Then update you exiting mapper to use this new mapper like this

```
@Mapper(uses = Mapper1.class)
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "from.id", target = "ref")
    To get(From from);
}
```